# Updating a custom web service

Tags: 2010, web-services, custom

I have created a custom web service on the sharepoint server (2010). I wanted to update the webservice, so I added the new assenbly to my virtual bin and GAC, it didn't look like the wsdl or disco files needed changed. When I run the web service, it runs the previous version and I know the assembly files have been updated. Does anyone know what the issue could be here?

Comment: IISRESET performed I hope? :)

Comment: oops, that is why! dumb mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need an `iisreset` to reload the assemblies.

If you packaged your web service as a WSP file, you can use [Update-SPSolution](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607724%28v=office.14%29.aspx) to update the WSP without retracting / re-deploying the solution.  This is a technique I use often when making changes to code that needs to get re-deployed, to save the time of the full retraction / deletion / addition / deployment cycle, while still keeping SharePoint "aware" that an update has been made.  It goes something like this:

```
update-spsolution -identity my.custom.wsp -literalpath c:\path\to\my.custom.wsp -gacdeployment

// then

iisreset

// then, if it's a timer job

restart-service sptimerv4
```